# Multimeter shows 4.3V AC AND DC

Tags: multimeter, voltage-measurement

Today I wanted o repair my door's buzzer system. After removing the front, there were a number of cables protruding from the wall. Pretty old building, so there was no clear color coding of the cables. Not even knowing whether dealing with AC or DC cables, I measured both possibilities. Strangely, some cables exhibited 4.3 V both for DC and AC option...

So I connected an LED to see if it lights up regardless of how it is installed. If this is the case, I thought, it must be AC. If it's lit only one-way, it must be DC. HOWEVER, it lighted up for one direction, and for the other direction it lighted up, too, only way dimmer, which I can't explain at all!

So am I dealing with AC or DC?

Comment: Digital meters are 10Mohm and if lines are open, you will get RFI and line noise .    You are dealing AC. What kind of LED determines the result as long as it does not exceed rating in forward or reverse. Old buzzers used a 24Vac transformer.  You should only get valid readings across switch when connected, or across wires when switch is closed. If high impedance then fingers across probe tip will change the levels, higher if on one, lower if shunting both probes for low V high impedance. You might be able to tape switch closed.

Comment: Thank you! What is RFI though?

Comment: rf interference